# Is it necessary to use transactions explicitly in Kafka Streams to get "effectively once" behaviour?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

A [Confluence article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/enabling-exactly-once-kafka-streams/) states

> Stream processing applications written in the Kafka Streams library can turn on exactly-once semantics by simply making a single config change, to set the config named “processing.guarantee” to “exactly_once” (default value is “at_least_once”), with no code change required.

But as transactions are said to be used, I would like to know: **Are transactions used implicitly by Kafka Streams, or do I have to use them explicitly?**

In other words, do I have to call something like `.beginTransaction()` and `.commitTransaction()`, or is all of this really being taken care of under the hood, and all that remains for me to be done is fine-tuning `commit.interval.ms` and `cache.max.bytes.buffering`?

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Streams is using the  transactions API to achieve exactly-once semantics implicitly, so you do not need to set any other configuration.

If you continue reading the blog it says:

> "More specifically, when `processing.guarantee` is configured to `exactly_once`, Kafka Streams sets the internal embedded producer client with a transaction id to **enable the idempotence and transactional messaging features, and also sets its consumer client with the read-committed mode to only fetch messages from committed transactions** from the upstream producers."

More details can be found in [KIP-129: Streams Exactly-Once Semantics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-129%3A+Streams+Exactly-Once+Semantics)